# login page with useing ip address for phpmyadmin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, ip

I was looking and can't find a way to set it so i just setup php my admin and my client put his IP Address, username, and password in so he can log-in to php my admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Directory directive to your phpmyadmin.conf file:

```
<Directory "/path/to/phpmyadmin">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 0.0.0.1
  Allow from 0.0.0.2
</Directory>
```

where 0.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.2 are IPs you'd like to restrict access to.  You probably don't want him having to type his IP address into a box as part of the user/pass flow.  Much better to simply set it on your server end.

More information on locking down PHPMyAdmin can be found here: http://www.linuxbrigade.com/lock-down-your-phpmyadmin-access/

Comment: I'm not adding ip address, im allow to using the website cms to manage there mysql, but im providing the website to do so, i want a area for them to put there ip address, username, and password, so then they can log-in and view the sql.

Comment: OK, perhaps add that to your original question.  Why do they need to add an IP address?  If you made sure the user/pass were unique you could do without that functionality altogether.

Comment: I'm not hosting the sql server but im hosting the website that has the phpmyadmin